# How to show subcategories of a selected main category?

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a navigation that when the user selects a category then the navigation will only show sub categories for that category selected.

I'm getting a variable from the URL to pass as the parent id and it looks like so:

```
locolhost/store.php?c=2
```

the navigation I'm looking for should look like:

```
Parent
    child
    child
Parent
Parent
Parent
```

but, currently my code produces:

```
Parent
    child
    child
Parent
    child
    child
Parent
    child
    child
Parent
    child
    child
```

Here's my current code:

**shop.php**

```
$parent_id = $_GET['p'];
include('navigation.php');
$navigation = new navigation;
print($navigation->main($parent_id));
```

**navigation.php**

```
public function main($parent)
{
    /* PDO */
    $array = $categoryVIEW->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $this->buildNav($array,$parent);
}
private function buildNav($array,$parent)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent'] === NULL)
        {
            $html .= "\n<div class=\"parent\"><a href=\"?p=".$item['category_id']."\">".$item['category_name']."</a></div>\n";
            $html .= "<div class=\"child\">\n";
            $html .= $this->getChildren($array,$parent);
            $html .= "</div>\n";
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
private function getChildren($array,$parent)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent']===$parent)
        {
            $html .= "\t<a href=\"?p=".$item['category_id']."\">".$item['category_name']."</a>\n";
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

I'm just simply calling called `getChildren()` from `buildNav()` which gets all the children for the selected category. I think I need a condition that will call `getChildren()` only when the parent I want to show it's children is going through the loop ... if that makes sense?

Here's my database:

[image]

Comment: I am confused with your title and `curently I'm getting:` section

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I mean is when I run the current code that's the output.

Comment: can you print `parentid` along with your output.. still i cant figure out what exactly is ur problem!!

Comment: Why u are fetching the childnode of all the categories? you can filter it by using `parent=$parent_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ... I needed to add a condition. Here's the working code:

```
private function buildNav($array,$parent)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent'] === NULL)
        {
            $html .= "\n<div class=\"parent\"><a href=\"?p=".$item['category_id']."\">".$item['category_name']."</a></div>\n";
            $html .= "<div class=\"child\">\n";

            /* had to add this condition */
            if($item['category_id'] === $parent)
            {
                $html .= $this->getChildren($array,$parent);
            }               
            $html .= "</div>\n";
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
private function getChildren($array,$parent)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent'] === $parent)
        {
            $html .= "\t<a href=\"?p=".$item['category_id']."\">".$item['category_name']."</a>\n";
        }           
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you are passing the correct 'parent' variable to the child function. Try the following:

```
private function buildNav($array,$parent)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach($array as $item)
    {
        if($item['parent'] === NULL)
        {
            $html .= "\n<div class=\"parent\"><a href=\"?p=".$item['category_id']."\">".$item['category_name']."</a></div>\n";
            $html .= "<div class=\"child\">\n";
            // the following line needs to be changed
            $html .= $this->getChildren($array,$item['category_id']);
            $html .= "</div>\n";
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: After seeing your example, I did notice something that might help. Currently I have `$this->buildNav($array,NULL)` I'm thinking I should call the parent id of the children I want to see. So for example `buildNav($array,2)`

Comment: Hmm, are you sure? Looking at this example it works. (note I have made some changes so it will work outside of your object/class). http://codepad.org/euF9VLoR

Comment: I updated my post to help clarify my problem. It was pretty vague ;)

Comment: Im pretty sure that line is the only problem. Did you see this working correctly? http://codepad.org/euF9VLoR

Comment: Hey Hank, the reason your pastebin shows only children for one category is because there are only two children in your array. I've created a pastebin with my array having all the items that are in my database screenshot. Here is the link -> http://codepad.org/tyjFUePv. As you can see all the children are showing instead of only the children of the desired category.